# How can we get absolute position of draggable stop event in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I am working on draggable element, it is working fine for me, only issue with it i am not able to get absolute position of body, can anyone please help me how can i get draggable absolute position on stop event ? Here is my code for that

```
$(".main_line").draggable({
            stop: function(event, ui) {
            var pos = $(this).parent().position();
            console.log(pos);
            } 
        });
```

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you're asking for - perhaps providing some sample HTML will help? When you say "absolute position of body", do you mean the literal `body` element? Or the position of the `.main-line` parent element in the DOM? Or where it's dragged to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For doing that, you can use [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) like below:

```
$(".main_line").draggable({
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    var pos = $(this).offset();
    console.log(pos);
  }
});
```

[**Online Demo (FiddleJs)**](https://fiddle.jshell.net/6h78hz7n/5/)